# Can UWP services be created, which remain active regardless of battery state?

Tags: c#, service, uwp, windows-10

While the lifetime management for UWP apps is very well explained by the life cycle etc, I fail to find reliable information about `UWP services`.
There is a very thin article about [UWP services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service#create-the-app-service). Some other information is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/guidelines-for-background-tasks).

Basically they are implemented as background task which can be in-process or out-of-process.

While conserving battery energy is the main design intent in those life cycle concepts I am looking for a way of creating a service that is guaranteed to run and never be terminated.

The one option would be a `windows service` but I am evaluating whether it is currently possible to spawn a uwp service that has no foreground activity and uses OS' mechanism to ensure that the background service runs for ever.

There are things indicating that this is not possible, like

> CPU quotas: Background tasks are limited by the amount of wall-clock
>   usage time they get based on trigger type. **Most triggers are limited
>   to 30 seconds of wall-clock usage, while some have the ability to run
>   up to 10 minutes in order to complete intensive tasks**. Background
>   tasks should be lightweight to save battery life and provide a better
>   user experience for foreground apps. See Support your app with
>   background tasks for the resource constraints applied to background
>   tasks.

My requirements for the background process would be that in no case the background service must be terminated (e.g it provides critical functionality).
Additionally this service should provide functionality to a set of stand alone UWP apps (that's why I am looking at UWP services)

(I am aware that for UWP the defined behaviour has and might change in future.)

Comment: Try and look for wcf services. They could be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Windows Creators Update (version 1703) background tasks may run indefinitely using the `extendedBackgroundTaskTime` capability. Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-in-the-background-indefinetly) for more information.

You may also prevent a UWP desktop app from being suspended as explained in [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2018/01/30/non-suspending-uwp-desktop-apps/) article.

Comment: Excellent answer. Tracking all the behavioural deltas of those UWP updates appears to be quite complicated :)